# How to get firefox to read UTF-16 JSON

Tags: firefox, server, character-encoding

Ok so I got a web server serving UTF-16 jsons.
UTF-16 needed so don't even dare to answer "why don't you switch to UTF-8".

Apparently firefox can't read them.
In fact i get a JSON.parse error... 
I tried switching to UTF-8 to prove that's the problem and it works... 
but how can i make it successfully decode UTF-16?

my response headers charset is  already "UTF-16"

Comment: I won't ask why UTF-16 is needed (and I suppose it "should" still work) but in case you are not aware and need a justification to switch, the new JSON standard ([RFC 8259](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#page-9)) drops UTF-16 and UTF-32, leaving only UTF-8 as inter-system encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is you can't... Not with up to date versions of Firefox at least....